# Select an item from Dojo Grid's store and display one of its attributes (array of objects) on grid

Tags: dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid, dojo

I have a Dojo EnhancedGrid which uses a data store filled with the following data structure:

```
[ 
  { id: 1, desc: "Obj Desc", options: [ { txt: "text", value: 0 }, { obj2 }, { objn } ] },
  { id: 2, ... },
  { id: 3, ... },
  { id: n, ... }
]
```

Currently I'm doing all this with an auxiliary store...but I believe this is far from a good approach to the problem, it's too ugly and doesn't work really well with edition (because I have to send changes from one store to another).

Instead of displaying all this objects at the same time, I wanted to select just one object (using its id) and display its options objects on grid. At the same time, the changes on grid should make effect on store, to be able to save them later.

Is it possible to query the grid's store, in order to display just one object? How?
And is it possible to fill the grid with objects list present on "options" attribute?